# Does websites know the folder name when I upload a file from that folder?

Tags: safari, upload

If I'm uploading a file to a website from a folder called "XXX", does the website know that I'm uploading that file from "XXX"?

In essence, will the website know the folder name?

Note: I use Safari on Mac.

Comment: I believe it is masked by the browser that is uploading the file.

Comment: @Moab I'm using Safari by the way.  Is that true for Safari?

Comment: I think it is true for all browsers.

Comment: @Moab Ah great, thanks! May I ask how did you know this?

Comment: Because it would be a huge security hole if they did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is not supposed to send the folder part to the website,
as this might be taken as a form of attack.

From
[RFC 6266 - Use of the Content-Disposition Header Field in the
Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266)

:

> **Recipients MUST NOT be able to write into any location other than
> one to which they are specifically entitled**.  To illustrate the
> problem, consider the consequences of being able to overwrite
> well-known system locations (such as "/etc/passwd").  One strategy
> to achieve this is to never trust folder name information in the
> filename parameter, for instance by stripping all but the last
> path segment and only considering the actual filename (where 'path
> segments' are the components of the field value delimited by the
> path separator characters "" and "/").

Any browser that includes the folder-part in the sent file-name risks being
cut-off by security services on the server website.
As far as I know, no browser does it.